# Prove/Disprove that $f(n) + g(n)= O(g(n)*f(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I would like to know if this statement is true:
[image]

I thought of giving a counter example by defining:
[image]
 which will give us that [image] but i'm nut sure if it's possible to say that [image] beacuse I suspect that it might be right because of the definition of Big O.

And if that's right that means that the counter example i gave is not good.
Am i right? or the statement is true? If it's true, how am I suppose to approach such questions?